# How to track down app's increasing memory with Instruments?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I have an iOS Swift app that frequently freezes and I see that memory consumption in the Simulator increases continuously. It happens a lot if I repeatedly switch between tabs in the tab bar, but sometimes I cannot reproduce it at all.

When the app freezes, I am able to see the memory rising continuously in the Xcode debug navigator:

[image]

I already tried to use the Leaks module of Instruments but there was nothing noticeable. How else can I track down the bug in Instruments?

Answer (score 0):

I found the object that increased the memory by using the Allocations module of Xcode Instruments. The issue was related to `NSContentSizeLayoutContraint` which was identified by looking at the growing `# Persistent` memory allocation.

[image]

The solution was to change the layout constraints for a `UILabel` in the `UICollectionViewCell` and only anchoring to contentView instead of anchoring to another view inside the content View. That has caused the issue for some reason.